# Select2: How to select the "value" of an option?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select

I have a dropdown of countries:

```
<select size="1" class="product-load-port" name="product-load-port">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="AX">Aland Islands</option>
  <option value="AL">Albania</option>
  <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
</select>
```

How to select the value of the chosen country, ex. if Albania was chosen, value should be "AL"?

I'm trying to do that with

```
$('select.product-load-port').select2('data')[0].text;
```

but it gives me "Albania" as a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by simply accessing the `.val()` of the underlying native `<select>` element:

```
$('select.product-load-port').val()
```

You can also proxy it through `.select2().val()`, but that's not really necessary anyway:

```
$('select.product-load-port').select2().val()
```

```js
$('select.product-load-port').select2();

$('#getSelectedValue').on('click', function() {
  console.log($('select.product-load-port').val());
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select size="1" class="product-load-port" name="product-load-port">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="AX">Aland Islands</option>
  <option value="AL">Albania</option>
  <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
</select>

<button type="button" id="getSelectedValue">Log selected value to console</button>
```